# Name attribute gets removed from FORM tag in .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, angularjs

How do I make sure .NET does not remove the NAME attribute from my HTML forms. I require this in order to use AngularJS. Please let me know.

in visualstudio my form looks like this:

```
<form id="scheduleFrm" name="scheduleFrm" runat="server">
```

but it ends up looking like this in my browser's source:

```
<form id="scheduleFrm" method="POST"> without the name attribute
```

AngularJS needs the name attribute but name is available for my form

Comment: are you using mvc? put your html code for your form, please.

Comment: my form tag looks like this:

<form id="scheduleFrm" name="scheduleFrm" runat="server">

but it removes the name="scheduleFrm" why I look at the source in my browser

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE: `runat="server"` points towards ASP.Net, unless there's another usage of which I'm not aware.

Comment: I am wondering why it wont maintain the name attribute and still use runat="server"

Comment: @user, see [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes): `The HtmlForm control does not render a name attribute`. I don't think there is a workaround.

Comment: @Flater yes, I know, but he put html form code after my question. :)

Comment: @user3214892, if you can't change form's name, so you can change your angular code. I think you're using this to do validation? If yes, I put an answer to your question.

Comment: yes I am trying to do some validation but I can make use of the form name. I am new to angularJS and the examples I see on the net make use of the form name.

Comment: Does the following setting in web.config not revert back to .net outputting names.. `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There is workaround you didn't read the section completely. You can add this setting `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />` to use Legacy rendering.

Answer (score 2):

This is bad but it will get you going again:

```
<form id="theName" ...>
    <script>document.getElementById("theName").setAttribute("name", "theName");</script>
    <!-- ...formalities -->
</form>
```

Comment: <form>

<script>
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form'); 
if (form.length > 0) { 
  form[0].setAttribute('name', 'aspnetForm');
}
</script>
...

Answer (score 0):

There is an workaround. If you do for example:

```
$scope.scheduleFrm...
```

to access your form, so you can do:

```
var formName = $("#scheduleFrm").attr("name");
$scope[formName]...
```

to do the same.